# TypeScript how to format array of object to array of json

Tags: json, mongodb, angular, typescript

I have posted data like `_attachments` variable:
[image]

I want to prepare that data to insert as the following structure:

```
"_attachments": [
  {
    "container": "string",
    "fileName": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "mime": "string",
    "size": 0
  }
]
```

But what i have done:

```
for(let key in _attachments) {
  job._attachments[key]['container']  = _attachments[key]['container'];
  job._attachments[key]['fileName']  = _attachments[key]['fileName'];
  job._attachments[key]['name']      = _attachments[key]['name'];
  job._attachments[key]['mime']      = _attachments[key]['mime'];
  job._attachments[key]['size']      = _attachments[key]['size'];
}
```

give this error:

```
 Unprocessable Entity
```

Note: I'm using loopback.

Comment: Unprocessable entity at? Mongodb side?

Comment: @Aravind When i post data to api for inserting this error occurre.

Comment: have you checked it by setting `job._attachments = _attachments` directly ? As per your object keys, i think you don't need to loop through all '_attachments'

Answer (score 4):

Just add this to your `attachment.josn`:

```
"id": {
  "type": "string",
  "id": true,
  "defaultFn": "uuid"
}
```

and no need to loop the data.

Answer (score 3):

From the screen shot `_attachments` seems to be an array; if that is that case you should not use `for...in` to iterate over it but `for..of`. `for..in` will return all enumerable properties including potentially "unwanted" ones

See the bottom of this [excellent MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for details (`for..of` is available in Typescript)

```
for (let index of _attachments) {
...
}
```

Even better, use a map

```
const result  = _attachments.map( att => ...)
```

Also the structure you map to seem identical to the original structure, why not use a direct assignment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Stringify it.

**Code**

```
data = { 
    container: "Stuff"
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data); 

console.log(jsonString);
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

This is more what your data looks like,

[image]

Comment: Still shows the same problem when i want to insert data

Comment: But if i upload single file, my insertion is working.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify will help you to get object in json format and JSON.parse will convert back from JSON to object.